# Cosets and Modulo

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

For any integer n greater than 1, psi(n) denotes the number of positive integers less than n and relatively prime to n. Prove that if a is any integer relatively prime to n, then a^psi(n)modn = 1

I was thinking of using Fermats Little Theorem, or some manipulation of U(n), but I cannot put together an adequate proof. Can I have some advice, or step by step explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a is relatively prime to n, then it exists in U(n).  phi(n)=order(U(n)) and order of a in U(n) must divide the order of U(n).  Therefore, the phi(n)=k*order of a in U(n).  a^phi(n)=a^(order of a in U(n))*k=e^k=1.

Answer (score 0):

If $\phi(m) = n$

$(a_1m)(a_2m)...(a_nm) \equiv a_1a_2...a_n \pmod m$

Where $a_1, a_2, ... a_n$ are all the numbers less than m that are coprime to m.

Now $a_1a_2...a_n$ can be cancelled on both sides as it is coprime to m, leaving $m^n \equiv 1 \pmod m \Rightarrow m^{\phi(m)} \equiv 1 \pmod m$